# How do I run OpenCV with the python3 command as opposed to the python command?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv

I'm running a python code that only works with the python3 command in the Ubuntu command line. I want to add OpenCV, but it only works with the python command. What do I have to do in order for OpenCV to work with python3? Here is an example of when I run both commands:[image]

Comment: did you try installing it with `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: Thank you. It works now.